# OrientDB execute script asynchronously and fetch records in a lazy fashion

Tags: asynchronous, lazy-loading, orientdb, orientdb2.2

Currently, we are using the Document API in OrientDB version 2.2. Let us suppose we have a class Company and a class Employee. Let's suppose we are interested in all Companies with at least one employee having a name from an arbitrary list. Employees are defined as LINKEDLISTs in our Company schema. 
Our query would look smth like this:

```
select from Company where employees in (select from Employee where name in ["John", "Paul"])
```

Currently we have defined the following two indexes:

Company.employees (index on the employee links (their @rid)) -> dictionary hash index and 
Employee.name -> notunique index

When executing the above query with explain we see that only the second index Employee.name is used, since we did not define the above indexes as a compound index. AS far as I could understand compound indexes across different classes like in our case are not supported in Orient 2.x.
Queries like this:

```
select from Company let $e = select from employees where name in ["John", "Paul"] where employees in $e
```

do not solve our problem either.

Searching across different blogs revealed two suggestions so far:

1. trying to define a compound index via inheritance by introducing a parent class on employee and company and defining the above two indexes on that

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5069

2. bundle the two queries in a batch scrip like this:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6684

> String cmd = "begin\n";
>           cmd += "let a = select from Employees where name " + query + "\n";
>           cmd += "let b = select from Company where employees in $a\n";
>           cmd += "COMMIT\n";
>           cmd += "return $b";

Suggestion 1 did not work for us.

Suggestion 2. worked. Both indexes have been used in each separate query, but then we ran into the next limitation of Orient. Batch scripts seem to be executed only **synchronously**, meaning that we can only get the results as a list all at once and not one by one in a lazy fashion, which in our case is a NO GO due to the memory overhead.

One naive workaround we tried is as follows:

```
public class OCommandAsyncScript extends OCommandScript implements OCommandRequestAsynch{
  public OCommandAsyncScript(String sql, String cmd) {
    super(sql, cmd);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAsynchronous() {
    return true;
  }

  private void containsAtLeastOne(final @Nonnull ODatabaseDocumentTx documentTx,
                                  final @Nonnull Consumer<Company> matchConsumer,
                                  final @Nonnull String queryText
                                  ) throws TimeoutException {

    String cmd = "begin\n";
    cmd += "let a = select from Employee where name " + queryText + "\n";
    cmd += "let b = select from Company where employees in $a\n";
    cmd += "COMMIT\n";
    cmd += "return $b";
    final OCommandHandler resultListener = new OCommandHandler(documentTx, (document -> {
      final Company companies = document2model(document);
      matchConsumer.accept(company);
    }));

    OCommandAsyncScript request =  new OCommandAsyncScript("sql", cmd);
    request.setResultListener(resultListener);
    documentTx.command(request).execute();
    ...
  }
}


public class OCommandHandler implements OCommandResultListener {
  private final ODatabaseDocumentTx database;
  private final Consumer<ODocument> matchConsumer;

  public OCommandHandler(
      final @Nonnull ODatabaseDocumentTx database,
      final @Nonnull Consumer<ODocument> matchConsumer
    ) {
    this.database = database;
    this.matchConsumer = matchConsumer;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean result(Object iRecord) {
    if (iRecord != null) {

      final ODocument document = (ODocument) iRecord;

      /*
      Result handler might be asynchronous, if document is loaded in a lazy mode,
      database will be queries to fetch various fields. Need to activate it on the current thread.
      */
      database.activateOnCurrentThread();
      matchConsumer.accept(document);
    }
    return true;
  }
  ...
}
```

The approach of defining a custom OCommandAsyncScript  did not work unfortunately. When debugging the OStorageRemote class of Orient it seems that no partial results could be read, Here the respective extract from the source code:

```
public Object command(final OCommandRequestText iCommand) {
....

try {
  OStorageRemote.this.beginResponse(network, session);
  List<ORecord> temporaryResults = new ArrayList();
  boolean addNextRecord = true;
  byte status;
  if(asynch) {
    while((status = network.readByte()) > 0) {
      ORecord record = (ORecord)OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(network);
      if(record != null) {
        switch(status) {
          case 1:
            if(addNextRecord) {
              addNextRecord = iCommand.getResultListener().result(record);
              database.getLocalCache().updateRecord(record);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
          if(record.getIdentity().getClusterId() == -2) {
              temporaryResults.add(record);
            }
          database.getLocalCache().updateRecord(record);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Network.readbyte() is always null, hence no records could be fetched at all.

Is there any other workaround how we could execute a sql script in asynchronus mode and retrieve results in a lazy fashion preventing the generation of large lists on our application side?